# How to include foreign key field when serialising search query result from django haystack

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, django-oscar

After googling a lot, I cant seem to find a solution to this:
I have created a new endpoint for searching items from my Product Index

Using Django oscar with django oscar api, here are the models:

```
class Product(AbstractProduct):
   title = models.TextField(blank = True)

class ProductImage(AbstractProductImage):
    product = models.ForeignKey('catalogue.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    remote_image = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

The views.py

```
class ItemSearchViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ItemSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        queryset = EmptySearchQuerySet()

        if request.GET.get('q', ''):
            query = request.GET.get('q', '')
            queryset = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
        return queryset
```

Serializers.py

```
from oscarapi.serializers import product

class ItemSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    text = serializers.CharField()
    title = serializers.CharField()
    price = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='product-price')
    image = product.ProductImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)  

    class Meta():
        model = Product
        fields = ('image', 'price', 'text', 'title')
```

When I hit the endpoint with `localhost:8000/api/search/?q=bmw`, it seems works for all other fields but does not return images, here is sample:

```
[
    {
        "image": null,
        "price": "http://localhost:8000/api/products/2339/price/",
        "text": "2339\nBMW 316 SE Automatic",
        "title": "BMW 316 SE Automatic"
    },
    {
        "image": null,
        "price": "http://localhost:8000/api/products/0029/price/",
        "text": "0029\nBmw 330d\nLoverly car in excellent condition",
        "title": "Bmw 330d"
    }]
```

Another thing, as there maybe several images for a given product, I would also like to just return the first image, which will have a `display_order` value of 1.

Comment: Try `images = product.ProductImageSerializer(source='productimage_set', many=True, required=False)` since DRF won't automatically serve the reverse relation unless specified.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r, Thanks for the response, but I resolved the issue by creating an index that includes images. That way I was able to reference images the same way I reference other fields